# This app won’t download on iPad and it won't let me delete

Tags: ipad, applications, ipados

So far I have tried:

- Press and holding on the app
- System Prefs -> General -> Storage

[image]

Comment: What region are you in? I looked for this app and cannot find it.

Comment: If the app is mingled in with your other apps, hold on the app until it (and other apps) start to wiggle, then tap the X to delete.

Comment: If powering down the iPad and then trying the answers linked - an edit might make this new enough to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you have the app offloaded. Go back into the storage settings, "reinstall" (or un-offload) the app, then try deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you long-press the app, click "Prioritise Download", long-press the app again and click "Cancel Download", the app should disappear.

I did not have the same problem but when there are apps queuing and I  want to remove them, I do this and it works.